# Strange chef issue evaluation of true/false

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have ran into strange issue (bug) with with chef-client (12.18.31, embedded Ruby is ruby 2.3.1p112) on Windows. It is not enough to use value of node attribute within recipe - I need to compare it against against `true`. To be specific:

```
desired_mcafee_state =
  node['McAfee_enabled'] ? [:enable, :start] : [:disable, :stop]

puts "DEBUG: McAfee is #{node['McAfee_enabled']}, desired state is: #{desired_mcafee_state}"
```

This produces debugging output:

```
DEBUG: McAfee is false, desired state is: [:enable, :start]
```

while this syntax:

```
desired_mcafee_state =
  node['McAfee_enabled'] == true ? [:enable, :start] : [:disable, :stop]

puts "DEBUG: McAfee is #{node['McAfee_enabled']}, desired state is: #{desired_mcafee_state}"
```

correctly produces:

```
DEBUG: McAfee is false, desired state is: [:disable, :stop]
```

This works fine in irb:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> node={}
=> {}
irb(main):002:0> node['McAfee_enabled']=false
=> false
irb(main):003:0> desired_mcafee_state =
irb(main):004:0* node['McAfee_enabled'] ? [:enable, :start] : 
[:disable, :stop]
=> [:disable, :stop]
```

A bug or a Chef weirdness I don't understand?

Comment: In that first example, are you sure it isnt the string `"false"`?

Comment: If it's a string, be careful, as "true" != true

Comment: And importantly, "false" is a truthy value (because every string is a truthy value).

Comment: Yes. Stupid me... I set it in `attributes/default.rb` to `true`, but in json definition file for the environment it was set to `"false"`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved in comments, the value was the string `"false"`, which in Ruby's view of the world is truthy.